# User.Identity me devuelve null

Tags: c#, identityuser

Cuando inicio sesión con mi cuenta de microsoft, se para en la linea del código en el que tengo la variable del `AgenteId`, devolviendome una excepción de null.

```
var correo = (User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).Name;
            if (correo.Contains("#"))
                correo = correo.Substring(correo.IndexOf("#") + 1);

int AgenteId = db.Agentes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Correo == correo).AgenteId;
```

Y la variable correo obtiene el correo del usuario que esta ingresando al sistema. Que a su vez para obtener el Id del "usuario" por medio del correo.

Y en la variable correo no me devuelve el correo que pongo al accesar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de eliminar los comentarios para mantener el orden en el sitio, todo ha sido trasladado al chat. Te sugiero hacer lo mismo.

Comment: Este es el chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141317/discussion-between-luis-and-fredyfx